# Error while compiling "ant" build

Tags: android, cordova, ant, localnotification

Recently I installed [cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) plugin in my cordova app. I am getting following error while running `ant debug install` command:

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 42 source files to /home/project-path/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] /home/project-path/platforms/android/src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/notification/Options.java:262: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             return NotificationCompat.COLOR_DEFAULT;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable COLOR_DEFAULT
    [javac]   location: class NotificationCompat
    [javac] /home/project-path/platforms/android/src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/notification/Builder.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                 .setColor(options.getColor())
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method setColor(int)
    [javac]   location: class Builder
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 2 errors
    [javac] 3 warnings
```

Is there something I am missing? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by adding `android-support-v4.jar` to the app.